# Set background color for product title in Products of Elementor in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, background-color, title

I use WordPress + WooCommerce to develop a website. I implement Products widget in the Elementor. I want to have red background #EC1D38 for the product title as shown as the image. The default settings do not have the background color setting. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcPWY.jpg)

[Current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqtiP.jpg)

Comment: can you please share the page link

Comment: @FullStop He is required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: Next time I will take care of it @Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added one class in your div is called "fruits".

Please add the below CSS to your CSS file.

```
.fruits h2.woocommerce-loop-product__title {
    background: #ec1d38;
    color: white !important;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0;
}
.fruits li.product.type-product {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
.fruits a.button.product_type_simple {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Please accept this answer and delete the editor user in your account