# Changing background colour of Woocommerce account page

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

I am trying to change the background colour of the standard Woocommerce my account page. When I go onto the account page and click 'view orders', the rows of titles are all in white (which is the same colour as the font) so it's impossible to see.. i.e Order, Date, Status, Total. Screenshots attached. I just want to change the background colour to black so that the titles appear. (or atleast change the font colour to another colour other than white). I've tried fixing it via Elementor Site settings or even the customize option for wordpress but none of these actions alter the woocommerce account page. Looking for some custom CSS. (I know virtually nothing about coding and I am building a website for my business).
[Woocommerce My account picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9K95E.png)

Thanks.

Comment: This can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64532979/set-background-color-for-product-title-in-products-of-elementor-in-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

I've had a look and it appears there are a three or more relevant css classes. You can add and play with this css. Either under Appearance > Customize > Additonal CSS or using a child theme

```html
.woocommerce-MyAccount-content {
    background: black;
}

.woocommerce-info, .woocommerce-message {
    background: blue;
}
```

Good luck with it!

Comment: Hey there, Just dropping a quick tip : you can use code fences instead of snippets since the snippet feature here is not necessary